# PHP check if two strings has common parts?

Tags: php, string

The main string contains parts which are separated by #

I need to check if the incoming string contains any of the banned keys.

In real example the keys are made by md5($var), each key 32 character length. Number of keys are variable in both $banned_keys and $incoming_keys1

```
$banned_keys =  'abc1#abc2#abc3#abc4';

$incoming_keys1='asd1#asd2#asd3#asd4'; //should pass no banned key found
$incoming_keys2='asd1#asd2#asd3#abc3'; //Should fail, contains banned key 'abc3'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$banned_array = explode('#', $banned_keys);
$incoming_array = explode('#', $incoming_keys);

// compute intersection of two sets
if( array_intersect($banned_array, $incoming_array) )
 ...
```

Comment: I like this! Didn't know of array_intersect. Nice one :)

Comment: I believe array_intersect is better than in_array. This made my day!

Comment: And, if you don't need the arrays later: `if( array_intersect(explode('#', $banned_keys), explode('#', $incoming_keys)) )`

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the strings to arrays using `explode('#',$string)` for both the incoming and the banned keys, then use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check.

For example

```
$banned = explode('#','abc1#abc2#abc3#abc4');
$incoming = explode('#','asd1#asd2#asd3#asd4');
if(in_array($banned,$incoming)){
 //fail
}
```

There may be a better way, but this should work :)

Comment: only 32 characters of the incoimng string should match 32 characters of the banned... how do you say that with strpos()??Maybe I am missing something??

Comment: excellent  actually "in_array" is good one, I was trying to loop through so just gave up and looked for string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You could 'explode' the strings to transform them into arrays and then match the array entries (if the intersection contains any entries, at least one banned key is provided):

```
$banned_keys_ary = explode('#', $banned_keys);
$incoming_keys_ary = explode('#', $incoming_keys);
if (count(array_intersect($incoming_keys_ary, $banned_keys_ary)) > 0)
{
  // fail, at least one banned key found
}
else
{
  // pass, no banned keys found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
$banned_keys_array = explode("#", $banned_keys);
$incoming_keys_arr = explode("$", $incoming_keys);

$is_valid_key = true;
foreach($incoming_keys_arr as $key) {
  if (in_array($key, $banned_keys_array) {
     // Invalid key found;
     $is_valid_key = false;
     break;
  }
}

// check $is_valid_key here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking here:

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php#match

and for the Regular Expression..

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

I'm still new at using Regular Expression..

I guess for your problem, the pattern would be...

```
/abc1|abc2|abc3|abc4/g
```

then the could should be..

```
<?php
$subject = "asd1#asd2#asd3#asd4";
$pattern = '/abc1|abc2|abc3|abc4/g';
if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)) {
echo "Match was found <br />";
echo $matches[0];
}
?>
```

The preg_match() function returns 1 if a match is found and 0 otherwise.